# Re-awarding badges after merging accounts?

Tags: support, badges, user-accounts, merge-accounts

When [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) answered my question on [Merging Accounts Question Roundup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311529/merging-accounts-question-roundup?noredirect=1&lq=1), in part of their answer they said:

> *"Badges are not transferred, but will be automatically re-awarded as the processes run again."*

Suppose I had the badge "Scholar" with my secondary account, and I did not with my main account. After the merging process is over, would the badge show up in my showcase on my main account, or, would it just not be transferred over?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means exactly what it says. We don't copy the badges over on a merge. But the process that awards badge will give it to you again if you're still eligible for it at the time it runs. So if you still have a post that qualifies for Scholar, you'll receive it again whenever the process that awards it runs next.

That does mean you're not guaranteed to get *all* of the badges you had previously. If you earned a badge that you no longer qualify for on your secondary account, you won't earn it on your main account unless you later qualify for it again.

---

**For example:** You could have the [Curious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/242/curious) badge on your secondary account. That badge has the following requirement:

> Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record.

If you no longer have a positive question record due to the merger you no longer qualify for the badge, and therefore it won't be awarded.